# How to select only necessary part from each line txt file php

Tags: php, html, web

```
:jhjhjhjh.lklk@mail.ru:250cf8b51c773f3f8dc8b4be867a9a02:HHJ:24:red:male
:Khach.mail94@mail.ru:202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70:Khach:21:red:male
```

I have a txt file with two lines above.
During reading this file and iterating each line I want to select only part of email for example
from first ":" delimiter to second 
How can I set delimiters for cutting only necessary part from each line???

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: `explode(':', $line)[1]`